# PDF file size is wrong and file is corrupted after convert base64 PDF to Blob in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf, amazon-s3, base64

I am trying to convert my base64 PDF string back to PDF blob but while doing so size of file is changing and the file shows as corrupted.

Here is the Base64 string:-

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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
```

When i try to decode this string online with base64 to file tool, it decodes correctly

This is my code piece that is converting this string back to blob-

```
const b64toFile = (b64Data, filename) => {
  console.log(b64Data);
  var arr = b64Data.split(','),
  mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
  bin = atob(arr[1]);
  console.log('File Size:', Math.round(bin.length / 1024), 'KB');
  const len = bin.length;
  const arr1 = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr1[i] = bin.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  let blob = new Blob([arr1], {type: mime});
  console.log(blob);
};
```

I am getting the `mime` correctly as `application/pdf`

The output is coming like this:

```
File Size: 3 KB
{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "106f0e18-da0f-4b46-9aff-43d45506a954", "lastModified": undefined, "offset": 0, "size": 10801, "type": "application/pdf"}}
```

If you notice, the size became from 3KB to 10KB. After this when i try to open the file, it gives corrupted file error

This is how im fetching the file in react native:
(The file is rendering correctly till this point)

```
getDocumentFromS3(sub._id, DocumentTypes.tos).then(data => {
        if (data) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(data);
          reader.onloadend = function () {
            var base64data = reader.result;
            setTosFile(base64data.replace('octet-stream', 'pdf'));
          };
        } else {
          console.log('Agreement not generated yet');
        }
      });
```

NOTE:-

For those wondering what im trying to do, basically i render the pdf, sign the document and reupload it to the cloud.

But because uploaded file was getting corrupted, i commented the entire code in middle and now im just fetching it and then trying to reuploading the same exact file back to check whats the issue.
No operation is done on the file in middle now.

Comment: May be I missed it, but I don't see where in your code you decode the base64 data back to binary data.

Comment: b64toFile() is the method i found online for converting base64 back to blob for uploading to s3 again in formdata.. this that incorrect? @Robert

Comment: @KJ why do you say so? because of the 'octet-stream' ? i've meaning to fix that on the uploading end, the content type should go as application/pdf but somehow saves as octet.. i have a fix for that.. will that fix my upload issue too?

Comment: im using a presigned s3 url on aws to upload/download files and then fetching with the url received.. i did see some irregularity with this method because even the file name should ideally be Agreement.pdf but metadata shoes sample.pdf which was the original name before renaming

Comment: oh okay understood.. im going to try using a local pdf file and trying this process before i start using s3.. just to verify if that file received is the problem

Comment: Although is the process to convert base64 to blob correct in that method?

Comment: @KJ If you dont mind, could you help me with a code example.